# Single Channel OpenCV Mat.at<> gives out wrong values

Tags: c++, opencv, types, cout, mat

Declaring the Mat image, and assigning values.

```
Mat magnitude = Mat(gradient_columns.cols, gradient_columns.rows, CV_64FC1);
for(int i = 0; i < gradient_columns.cols; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < gradient_columns.rows; j++)
    {
        magnitude.at<double>(Point(i,j)) = (double)hypot(gradient_columns.at<double>(Point(i,j)), gradient_rows.at<double>(Point(i,j)));
    }
}
```

Printing the above Mat:

```
cout << "M = " << magnitude << endl;
```

Result:

```
M = [0, 0, 0.1257399049164523, 12.36316814720732, 12.50461780753356, 0.2674320707434279, 10.39230484541326, 12.03299037437945, 5.430256687374658, 
12.03299037437945, 4.684492386402418, 4.72934192083521, 12.16431633381293, 5.397674732957373, 12.30042244512288, 10.25834261322606, 0.3944487245360109, 
12.16431633381293, 11.84297951775486, 12.44187210544911, 12.10132213098092, 
0.4088817310696626, 10.15078660267586, 12.09573607646389, 2.076275433221507, 0, 0.1257399049164523, 0, 0.1257399049164523, 0;
.....
.....]
```

The above result is completely correct and as expected.

However if I try to print individual values I get wrong results:

```
cout.precision(20);
cout << "CHANNELS: " << magnitude.channels() << endl;
cout << magnitude.at<double>(Point(0, 2)) << endl; 
cout << magnitude.at<double>(Point(0, 3)) << endl; 
cout << magnitude.at<double>(Point(0, 4)) << endl; 
cout << magnitude.at<double>(Point(0, 5)) << endl; 

Result | Actual Value:
CHANNELS: 1
0.062870  |  0.1257399049164523,
0.000000  |  12.36316814720732,
0.031404  |  12.50461780753356,
0.000000  |  0.2674320707434279
```

I understand its some data type conversion issue, but if anyone can suggest any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your quesiton but instead of `Mat.at<double>(Point(i,j))`, I usually find it clearer to write `Mat.at<double>(j,i)`

Comment: one additional remark: For better performance you should exchange both for loops (iterate over rows in the outer loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there is nothing wrong with your matrix. You are just not printing what you think you are.

When writing `magnitude.at<double>(Point(0,2))`, you're not printing the number in line 0 and column 2 as you expected, but the number in line 2 and column 0. Try to write `magnitude.at<double>(0,2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having a similar issue and @Sunreef's answer does not work, check if you are accidentally using `mat.at<float>(_,_)` instead of `mat.at<double>(_,_)`